# XNA Content Loading works on my machine but not others

Tags: xna, c#

I'm using `XNAWinForm` series 2 from App Hub for some task that needs 3d rendering.
It works fine on my PC, but I have problems in running this code on other machines.

I installed XNA framework redistributable on that machine, I tried 32 and 64bit computers and still its not working.
Even [the code on app hub](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) is not working on other machines.

What should I do?

Comment: You should collect and analyze any error messages produced.

Comment: there is no error when i debug it, as i said, it works fine on my machine.
and it on other machines before run completely, it closes, and no error again.

Comment: Have you tried starting the executable from the command line and seeing what it returns? Or tried using [Windbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) or some other debugger and attaching it to the executable? You should also add error handling to your program. I assume since you're doing content loading it's not finding the content it needs and crashing out. Make sure when that happens that you output a stack trace and an error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the **full XNA game studio** installed on every machine that will use your tool. From the WinForms2 sample page you linked to:

> Note also that the XNA Framework redistributable installer doesn't
>   include the Content Pipeline. This sample will run only on computers
>   that have the XNA Game Studio installed.

You also aren't allowed to distribute the full XNA studio installer in your install package, so if you are creating a tool to be distributed with your game the content pipeline isn't a great fit. It's likely not reasonable to expect end-users to install a developer tool to be able to use your custom tool.

Comment: so it means there is no solution for that? i mean changing the code to not use XNA dveloper tool or content pipeline? 
and i must install full XNA developer?

Comment: Yes, in order to build using the content pipeline (even in an automated tool) you need to have the full XNA game studio installed. There is no way around it - the required assemblies are not installed using the redistributable alone.